# How to Include source directory to Padre IDE?

Tags: perl, ide, include, include-path, padre

How do you include source directory to Padre IDE for autocomplete and for running the script.

Comment: pls explain your question a bit more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) there is a configuration option for setting the Perl interpreter arguments.

b) Set the PERL5LIB environment variable to your include paths

c) Create an empty padre.yml file in your project home dir, Padre will use this as the working dir, otherwise it's the file's dir.

The autocomplete function is using the current file and a perltags file (if one exists).